# cakephp, how to save data in two tables?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

i have a simple form with two input fields and i would like to save the data from one field inside one table and the other one inside the second table.

to save the data i use `$this->Room->save($this->data)`

any ideas how this can be done?

thanks

edit:

one is `rooms` the other one is `roomates`  the common key i want to use is  is `id_rooms` and `id_roomates`

Comment: Which are two tables & models ? Also It will be better you print array you get in $this->data.

Comment: Means, you have to save $this->data in roomates table too ? IS it saving properly in rooms table ?

Comment: well, i want some data stored in teh room table and some in the roomates one. i know i can get the data from teh form by using `$this->data` but i was wondering maybe i can pass what data i want to save. then i can say sometihn like

`$this->Roomtitles->save($this->data(array(some fields)))` and `$this->Room->save($this->data(array(some fields)))`

Comment: I suggest you to built the structure of your this->data as you want than save it

Comment: i already build it, i just want to save the data to multiple tables

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you face any problem to get it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4013/discussion-between-patrioticcow-and-rikesh-shah)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `Room` build an array like below. It is just an example, set it according to your actual fields.

```
$this->data['Room']['id_rooms'] = $this->data['Room']['id']
$this->data['Room']['abc'] = $this->data['Room']['xyz']
```

Then save data to room table: `$this->Room->save($this->data)`.

Next build an array for second table, say `Roomtitle`, as below:

```
$this->data['Roomtitle']['id_rooms'] = $this->data['Room']['id']
$this->data['Roomtitle']['abc'] = $this->data['Room']['xyz']
```

and save it: `$this->Roomtitle->save($this->data)`.